# "A struggle" or " in a struggle"

Tags: prepositions

This is a sentence of *The Guardian* newspaper, but I can not get it to me there is a missing of preposition.

> Getting a much skinnier stimulus package past Mitch McConnell, the veteran Republican Senate leader, will be a struggle.

In this sentence why they did not use the  preposition **'in'** in the last part like:

> "will be **in** a struggle"

Can you please give me any logic behind this?

Comment: Rescuing the canary from Tom, my pet cat, will be a struggle.

Comment: Read it as *getting a stimulus package past him will be a struggle* - the action is *getting the package past him*, and doing that *will be a struggle*, i.e. it will be difficult or a challenge, or it will involve a political battle.

Answer (score 2):

"[T]he veteran Republican Senate leader" is a separate clause within a compound sentence. As such, the final part of the sentence refers to and relies on the grammar from the first. You can read the sentence like this:

> Getting a much skinnier stimulus package past Mitch McConnell will be a struggle. Mitch McConnell is the veteran Republican Senate leader.

It would only be "*in* a struggle" if the sentence applied to Mitch McConnell (or another person), but it doesn't, it refers the act of pushing forwards the stimulus package itself.